# How can I make compile time assertions without C++11

Tags: c++, templates

In a job interview, I was asked to write a metafunction
that determined whether a type was a pointer. This is
what I presented:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_pointer
{ static const bool value = false; }

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer<T *>
{ static const bool value = true; }
```

Then I was asked to write a meta-assert, that will fail
during compile time if my `is_pointer` function is not
doing the right thing.

When I used `static_assert`, he explicitly told me that
I may only use C++98 standard. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think at this point you passed the "check to see if you actually know the language" part of the interview, unless the company makes C++ compilers or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case

```
template <bool> struct assert;
template <> struct assert<true> {};
```

would have solved the problem:

```
assert<!is_pointer<char>::value>();     // valid
assert<is_pointer<char *>::value>();    // valid

assert<is_pointer<char>::value>();      // compilation error:
                                        // use of incomplete class
```

Comment: That's not what SFINAE is (the solution is ok, but the name is misused).

Comment: This is also limited to locations where you can create an object of the type. To be able to use it in other contexts you would have to create fake objects: `// namespace: assert<condition> myassert;`

Answer (score 9):

There are different approaches, a common one trying to typedef an invalid type:

```
#define static_assert(condition) \
        typedef char assert ## __LINE__ [((condition)?1:-1)]
```

This can be used in mostly any context and will trip the compiler if the condition is false, since it would try to typedef an invalid type (array of negative number of elements). It can be used in different contexts:

```
// namespace level:
static_assert(sizeof(int)==4);
struct type {
   // class level:
   static_assert(sizeof(int)==4);
   void f() {
       // function level
       static_assert(sizeof(int)==4);
   }
};
```

Comment: This one can even be used in pure C :) But note that with your current macro the typedef will always be `assert__LINE__`, as is; to expand `__LINE__` to the actual line number you need an intermediate "join" macro call: [What should be done with macros that need to paste two tokens together?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/macros-with-token-pasting.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html). You can look at the code: [boost/static_assert.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/static_assert.hpp).

Here's a very simplified version, just to give you an idea:

```
#define JOIN(X, Y) DO_JOIN(X, Y)
#define DO_JOIN(X, Y) X ## Y

template<bool cond>
struct Static_assert_helper;  // incomplete type

template<>
struct Static_assert_helper<true> {
    typedef int Type;
};

#define STATIC_ASSERT(cond) \
    typedef Static_assert_helper<(cond)>::Type JOIN(Static_assert_typedef_, __LINE__)
```

It can be used in many places (see the documentation for examples).

(Boost's implementation is more complete, with e.g. a `sizeof` and an intermediate struct, to give a better error message and be portable on a wide range of compilers.)