# Understanding SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

As far as I know, SFINAE means substitution failures do not result in compilation errors, but just remove the prototype from the list of possible overloads.

What I do not understand: why is this SFINAE:

```
template <bool C, typename T = void> struct enable_if{};
template <typename T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

But this is not?

```
template <bool C> struct assert;
template <> struct assert<true>{};
```

From my understanding, the underlying logic is identical here. This question emerged from the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816978/how-can-i-make-compile-time-assertions-without-c11/17816993#17816993).

Comment: Neither code is SFINAE.

Comment: You seem to answer your own question: SFINAE does _not_ cause a compile-time error (if substitution fails), whereas the whole purpose of a static assertion _is_ to cause a compile-time error (is some condition is not true)

Comment: @jrok Wikipedia says `enable_if` is SFINAE, is it wrong?

Comment: `enable_if` template is an established way of *triggering* SFINAE in other context. But by itself, it's just a class template.

Comment: Maybe understanding SFINAE would be useless in C++14, could be better to understanding concepts lite?: http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s

Comment: (Funny to see how terminology-debate comments got replies and upvotes while mine apparently was completely ignored... :') )

Comment: @gx_ Maybe because it isn't just a mere terminology-debate? None of the code does in any way exhibit SFNINAE. If the OP does mean something else with it, he should clarify it. And your comment seems to answer a completely different question either (which probably is why it's a comment and not answer).

Comment: @ChristianRau It was basically about me not understanding what the term SFINAE means, and **why** the code does not exhibit SFINAE behavior.

Comment: @ChristianRau "Maybe because it isn't just a mere terminology-debate?" Probably... :) "And your comment seems to answer a completely different question either" Here I don't agree. Re-reading the question, my comment seems relevant (and was not intended to be an answer). But I agree with "he should clarify it". _Edit:_ Recent OP comments just made things more clear, thank you =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In C++98, SFINAE is done with either a return type or a function's dummy argument with default parameter

```
// SFINAE on return type for functions with fixed arguments (e.g. operator overloading)
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type
my_function(T const&);

// SFINAE on dummy argument with default parameter for functions with no return type (e.g. constructors)
template<class T>
void my_function(T const&, std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type* = nullptr);
```

In both cases, substution of `T` in order to get the nested type `type` is the essence of SFINAE. In contrast to `std::enable_if`, your `assert` template does **not have a nested type** that can be used in substitution part of SFINAE.

See Jonathan Wakely's excellent [ACCU 2013 presentation](http://accu.org/content/conf2013/Jonathan_Wakely_sfinae.pdf) for more details and also for the C++11 expression SFINAE. Among others (as pointed out by @BartekBanachewicz in the comments) is is now also possible to use SFINAE in function template default arguments

```
// use C++11 default function arguments, no clutter in function's signature!
template<class T, class dummy = typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type>
void my_function(T const&);
```

Comment: You can also do it in template argument list.

Comment: So `enable_if` **is not** SFINAE, but `typename enable_if<C>::type` **is** SFINAE, because it will not lead to an error if template substitution fails (as long as it is not the only match)?

Comment: @nijansen glad to have been of help. I also updated the answer with a link to an ACCU presentation.

Comment: @dyp: No, default template arguments are in C++98.  Otherwise you couldn't use `std::set<int>` as a shorthand for `std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >`.

Comment: @aschepler C++11 added default template arguments for *function templates*, your example is about *class templates* which were indeed in C++98

Comment: Yes, I see that.  But it is still possible to make use of SFINAE with default template arguments in C++98.

Comment: @aschepler Of course; I should've mentioned *function templates* somewhere in my comment. The point I wanted to make is that the second version in the first code block was not legal C++98/03, but that has been fixed now. (Removing comment..)