# SFINAE in C++98

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++98

I am trying to understand how does SFINAE work in C++98.
My aim is to write a simple template function that would only be called when
an integer is passed. But the plan is to do it without specializing a function for typename T = int, but definining a template function with a dummy parameter that checks wether the pased element is an integer. Heres my toy code :

```
// header.h

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

struct false_type {
    static const bool value = false;
};

struct true_type {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template < bool, typename T >
struct enable_if
{};

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
{ typedef T type; };

template <typename T>
struct is_integral : false_type {};

template <>
struct is_integral<int> : true_type {};

/* ... more is_integral specializations ... */

template < typename T > 
void print(T& value, typename enable_if<!is_integral<T>::value,T>::type* = 0)
{
    std::cout << "FIRST " << value << std::endl;
}

template < typename T > 
void print(T& value)
{
    std::cout << "SECOND " << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_integral<T>::value << std::endl;
}

// main.cpp

#include "header.hpp"

int main() {
    int a = 123;
    print<int>(a);
}
```

It is compiled as follows : `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++98 -pedantic -g3 -Wno-c++0x-compat main.cpp` .
I took the enable_if syntax from [this question's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829874/understanding-sfinae), which needed for an implementation of `enable_if` and `is_integral` to be carried out in C++98 (<type_traits> is not a C++98 header).
My problem is that this program outputs:

```
SECOND 123
true
```

My question is, why does this happen? I expected the first implementation of print to be called. Is my approach impossible (i.e. this can only be done by specializing a generic print function to int), or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: `enable_if<!is_integral<T>` - The condition is inverted compared to what you describe as wanting to happen.

Comment: If it helps, wiritng `typename enable_if<is_integral<T>::value,T>::type` as the second argument also calls the second print implementation. The code shown in the question tries to say "if there exists no pointer type to enable_if<cond>::type" which is the same as saying if cond is false, which for integers, it should be.

Comment: There may be a good reason for that as well, but the thing to bear in mind is that SFINAE is about *pruning* overloads. Overload resolution will still choose a best match from the unpruned ones. An immediate fix is to have both overloads constrained with inverted conditions.

Comment: "if there exists no pointer type to enable_if<cond>::type" - then the overload is **pruned**. You want it *not pruned*.

Comment: @carce-bo If you remove the `!`, the program will not compile. You'll get a error saying ambiguity error. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/RWT7fH-DA7)

Comment: I think I get it now. the `typename ... = 0` stands for "this argument is a dummy one" but not "this argument does not exist (i.e. type not defined) ". I was understanding it in the wrong way.

Comment: @Jason Liam yes I've been trying out some things given StoryTeller's comments.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation that mentions the `typename <something> = 0` syntax ?

Comment: @carce-bo You want that the function template should only be called when `T` is int right? Should i provide an answer?

Comment: @Jason Liam I do have now a compiling answer, but go ahead so I can see if we're on the same page.

Comment: @carce-bo See [this demo](https://onlinegdb.com/lZQ16XU9X), this will work only when `T` is int. You don't need any other overload.

Comment: Ok it is the same I have only difference is you wrote type* instead of type, which is trivial since one implies the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My aim is to **write a simple template function that would only be called when an integer is passed**.

There is no need to provide 2 overloads. You can just remove the `!` and have the first primary template as shown below:

```
template < typename T > 
void print(T& value, typename enable_if<is_integral<T>::value,T>::type* = 0)
{
    std::cout << "FIRST " << value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int a = 123;
    print<int>(a);  //works 
    //print<double>(4.4);                      //doesn't work
    //print<std::string>(std::string("f"));   //doesn't work
    //print(3.3);                             //doesn't work
    double d = 3.3;
    //print(d);                               //doesn't work
}
```